# SSD is disappearing and reappearing on Windows

Tags: ssd, asus-laptop, nvme

[Video](https://youtu.be/8Sr7SIjvhXE?si=usaNoy55gf996KY4)
I installed a NVMe SSD which is a Hynix OEM for Surface into my laptop.

If I use it as a data storage, it usually disappears when I wake up my laptop from sleep mode, or shut it down and restart it.

But if it is the Windows container, it has no problem.

And if I access to BIOS and then go into my Windows, it appears again.

- **My Laptop**: Asus X415EA
- **Motherboard**: X421EA
- **SSD Model Number**: hfm128gdgtng-87a0a

Comment: What is this "Windows container"?

Comment: Just the C:\ drive